# session storage on mongo DB is creating one line on DB for each http request and not one per login/sign up

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, express, session-storage

Using connect-mongo to handle session storage,  I am getting a lot of empty sessions in my mongo database (using mongolab), probably on every request (or very often). Here is an example:

```
{
"_id": "oThxLcz3PtztDWVxcKZvoADC",
"session": "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"passport\":{}}",
"expires": {
"$date": "2013-07-10T22:45:52.383Z"
}
}
```

As you can see, there is no user defined in the object. I read in another issue that it might be a difference of time between the server and the client so the cookies are expiring instantly but that's not the case, the sessions are working fine. Any idea how to have only a line every time somebody logs in or signs up? I don't want to pay extra storage on my database.
For info, I am using 2 dynos on Heroku and mongolab and my set up is:

```
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'secretkey',
store: new MongoStore({
      url:'mongodb://db:user@link:27468/dbname'
    })
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help you debug that issue, but I can suggest using connect-redis instead. The Redistogo nano instance on Heroku is free, and should support automatically expiring unused sessions so that you won't need a pricier option.

Comment: Yep, you are right, I am switching right, seems a lot more supported